# Color picking with AntiAliasing in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, antialiasing, color-picker, multisampling

I'm having a problem with color picking and antialiasing in OpenGL. When AA is activated results from glReadPixels are obviously wrong on object edges and object intersections. For example:

I render a box #28 (RGBA: 28, 0, 0, 0) near a box #32 (RGBA: 32, 0, 0, 0). With AA, I can get a wrong ReadPixel value (e.g. 30) where the cube and triangle overlap, or value of 14 on boxes edge, due to the AA algorithm.

I have ~4000 thousand objects I need to be able to pick (it's a jigsaw puzzle game). It is vital to be able to select objects by shape.

I've tried to disable AA with glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE) but it does not works with certain AA modes (I read it depends on AA implementation - SS, MS, CS ..)

So, how do I pick an underlying object?

1. A way do temporary disable AA?
2. Using a different buffer or even rendering context?
3. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Most graphic drivers have option to force anti aliasing ignoring your settings. [Try using FBO](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/570321-glreadpixel-selection--driver-forced-anti-aliasing/).

Comment: How about implementing picking independent from the rasterizer/OpenGL? There are easy to use, high performant libraries for ray-triangle intersection testing, like OPCODE http://www.codercorner.com/Opcode.htm

Comment: @datenwolf As he works with jigsaw puzzles (which I would implement as alpha tested quads or something similar), that won't work for him, I think.

Comment: @Christian: But then the test was even easier outside OpenGL (translate the picking coordinate into a coordinate of the Jigsaw texture and test for alpha value there, bypassing a slow OpenGL readback roundtrip). Honestly I was thinking about a 3D pieces jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: @datenwolf Ok, haven't thought about that. But still his color picking approach should be a bit easier, as without some space partitioning checking 4000 pieces won't be that efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use an FBO as your pick buffer?

Comment: I've rigged up FBO with color and depth attachements (for picking and unprojecting) and it worked out great. Thanks!

Comment: The only drawback is that some GPUs don't support FBO and yet have AA, then I need to fallback to main buffer colorpicking and problem returns

Answer (score 2):

I use this hack: pick not just one pixel, but all the 3x3=9 pixels around the picking point. If they are all same, we are safe. Otherwise, it must be on edge and we can skip that.

```
int renderer::pick_(int x, int y)
{
    static_assert(__BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__,
            "only works on little-endian architecture");
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4,
            "only works on architecture that has int size of 4");

    // sort of edge detection. selection only happens at non-edge
    // since the edge may cause anti-aliasing glitch
    int ids[3*3];
    glReadPixels(x-1, y-1, 3, 3, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ids);
    for (auto& id: ids) id &= 0x00FFFFFF;       // mask out alpha
    if (ids[0] == 0x00FFFFFF) return -1;        // pure white for background

    // prevent anti-aliasing glitch
    bool same = true;
    for (auto id: ids) same = (same && id == ids[0]);
    if (same) return ids[0];

    return -2;                                  // edge
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out a method to deal with antialiasing in p5.js and this technique of sampling 3x3 is a very creative solution!